# Can't load brcmfmac Broadcom driver

Tags: networking, drivers, broadcom

I have an issue where the bcrmfmac driver for a Broadcom 4360 wifi adapter is not properly loading, leaving the adapter unclaimed. A driver conflict or corruption, or something. I have two wifi adapters installed, and originally this Broadcom adapter worked fine out of the box, while the Intel AX200 adapter did not. After I got the Intel adapter working, the Broadcom adapter stopped working. When booting from a Ubuntu 2022.04.02 live USB, both drivers work out of the box with no additional drivers or configuration. I am running Ubuntu 2022.04.02 with kernel 5.19.0-46.

I have tried installing the firmware-b43-installer package, but this does not help, and I don't think this is installed out of the box when it was working before and on the live usb. I can't find any blacklist files for wifi adapters. I have tried re-installing the linux-firmware. Nothing works. The Broadcom adapter works fine on the live USB and Windows.

Running `sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma` gives "FATAL: Module wl not found.
Running `sudo mod probe brcmfmac` gives "ERROR: could not insert 'brcmfmac': invalid argument"

Does anyone have any suggestions on why the brcmfmac driver is not properly loading, and how to go about fixing this?

Output from the Ubuntu live USB where both wifi interfaces work out of the box:

```
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 1a
       serial: xxx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 cc-a0-72.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 01
       serial: xxx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.35.177.61 firmware=01-ea662a8c latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:110 memory:fc000000-fc007fff memory:fbc00000-fbffffff

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci | grep -i network
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
09:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
```

Output from the install with working AX200 and non-working Broadcom brcmfmac:

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 1a
       serial: xxx
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=73.35c0a2c6.0 cc-a0-73.ucode ip=192.168.50.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc500000-fc503fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fc000000-fc007fff memory:fbc00000-fbffffff
```

Running `sudo dmesg | grep brcmfmac` gives the following errors:

````
[ 4.491933] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_results (err -22)
[ 4.491959] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_scan_done
[ 4.491960] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_scan_done (err -22)
[ 4.491967] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped
[ 4.491968] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_sched_scan_stopped (err -22)
[ 4.491980] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired
[ 4.491981] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_remain_on_channel_expired (err -22)
[ 4.492186] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_register_netdevice
[ 4.492188] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_register_netdevice (err -22)
[ 4.492282] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_port_authorized
[ 4.492284] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_port_authorized (err -22)
[ 4.492298] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_new_sta
[ 4.492299] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_new_sta (err -22)
[ 4.492308] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_disconnected
[ 4.492309] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_disconnected (err -22)
[ 4.492328] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_new_nm
[ 4.492329] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol wiphy_new_nm (err -22)
[ 4.492335] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel
[ 4.492336] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ready_on_channel (err -22)
[ 4.492346] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_classify8021d
[ 4.492347] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_classify8021d (err -22)
[ 4.492353] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_crit_proto_stopped
[ 4.492354] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_crit_proto_stopped (err -22)
[ 4.492359] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_register
[ 4.492360] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol wiphy_register (err -22)
[ 4.492364] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb
[ 4.492364] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol __cfg80211_alloc_reply_skb (err -22)
[ 4.492370] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_put_bss
[ 4.492371] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_put_bss (err -22)
[ 4.492375] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_roamed
[ 4.492376] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_roamed (err -22)
[ 4.492388] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz
[ 4.492389] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol ieee80211_get_channel_khz (err -22)
[ 4.492395] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_check_combinations
[ 4.492396] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_check_combinations (err -22)
[ 4.492414] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined
[ 4.492415] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_ibss_joined (err -22)
[ 4.492426] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure
[ 4.492427] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_michael_mic_failure (err -22)
[ 4.492433] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory
[ 4.492434] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory (err -22)
[ 4.492448] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_rx_mgmt_khz (err -2)
[ 4.492479] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo
[ 4.492480] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_del_sta_sinfo (err -22)
[ 4.492493] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_unregister
[ 4.492494] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol wiphy_unregister (err -22)
[ 4.492600] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply
[ 4.492601] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_vendor_cmd_reply (err -22)
[ 4.492644] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_mgmt_tx_status (err -2)
[ 4.492676] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev
[ 4.492677] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_unregister_wdev (err -22)
[ 4.492743] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup
[ 4.492744] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_report_wowlan_wakeup (err -22)
[ 4.492766] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data
[ 4.492767] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_inform_bss_data (err -22)
[ 4.492787] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_connect_done
[ 4.492788] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_done (err -22)
[ 4.492797] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol wiphy_free
[ 4.492797] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol wiphy_free (err -22)
[ 4.492810] brcmfmac: disagrees about version of symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify
[ 4.492811] brcmfmac: Unknown symbol cfg80211_cqm_rssi_notify (err -22) ```
````